# RDD vs DataFrame performance

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

DataFrames are a fairly new concept to me. A handful of sources recommended it over RDDs and how it outperforms RDDs in many situations. I'd like to see if DataFrames are a viable option for (eventually, I'll be dealing with Array of bytes), so I compared the performance on a word count application on a 1GB file.

Anyways, when I ran the program, I got the following results:

RDD Count total: 137733312 Time Elapsed: 44.5675378 s

DF Count total: 137733312 Time Elapsed: 69.201253448 s

I was expecting the DataFrames to execute faster than the RDD. Is this a result of bad implementation? Or since the DataFrame implementation called textFile, the data was loaded into an RDD and then converted into a DataFrame. Does this impact the performance? Is it recommended to convert my file into say a Parquet file (since that's the default data source) and load directly from it?

I was wondering if someone could explain why RDD's outperformed DataFrames by a pretty significant margin.

```
def testDF(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext,
     fname: String, threshold: Int): Long = {
     import sqlContext.implicits._
     val linesDF = sc.textFile(fname).toDF("line")
     val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("line").setOutputCol("words")
     val wordsDF = tokenizer.transform(linesDF)
     val countUDF = udf((data: WrappedArray[String]) => data.size)
     val countTotal = wordsDF.withColumn("count", countUDF('words)).agg(sum("count"))

    countTotal.first()(0).asInstanceOf[Long]
}

def testRDD(sc: SparkContext, fname: String): Int = {
    // split each document into words
    val tokenized = sc.textFile(fname).flatMap(_.split(" "))

    // count the occurrence of each word
    val wordCounts = tokenized.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

    // count characters
    val countTotal: Int = wordCounts.map(_._2).reduce((a,b) => a + b)

    countTotal
}
```

Comment: so much for under the hood optimization!

Comment: Differences like `split()` vs `Tokenizer` makes me think you didn't really try to keep both implementations as close as possible. You sould, before concluding. Also would be good to know how many workers were there and how was load distributed in each test. Also [see this](https://www.adsquare.com/comparing-performance-of-spark-dataframes-api-to-spark-rdd/)